# Show records ordering by status value

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I have a table called communications in laravel and in it I have the status column, where status can be approved, error, pending, canceled. What I need is to bring all the records in order by status, where I define which one should appear first, for example:

all records that have error status

all records that have pending status

all records with approved status

Comment: you can use where clause laravel... like DB::table('communications')->where('status','pending')->get();        dont forget to import use DB; at top of page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

```
$query = "CASE WHEN status = 'error' THEN 1 ";
$query .= "WHEN status = 'pending' THEN 2 ";
$query .= "WHEN status = 'approved' THEN 3 ";
$query .= "ELSE 4 END ASC";
return $this->communication->query()->orderByRaw($query)->paginate($perPage);
```